# how to monitor dangling pointers that points to leakded memory?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, dangling-pointer

lets think we have a code like this :

```
 int * ptr = new int;
 int *nptr = ptr
 int * ptr2 = new int;
 int *nptr2 = 2*nptr+ptr2;
 delete ptr;
 delete ptr2;
 ptr = NULL;
 ptr2 = NULL;
```

So now the nptr and nptr2 is dangling pointer .I know that we can overload new allocating function to trace leaked memory (if we dont use delete command in code ) but dont know how to trace or monitor dangling pointers .

Comment: `int *nptr2 = 2*nptr+ptr2;` doesn't make any sense (it's essentially the same as `int *nptr2 = &ptr2[2 * nptr];`)

Comment: And dangling pointers doesn't lead to leaks, forgetting to `delete` memory leads to leaks. A dangling pointer can't be dereferenced or passed to `delete`.

Comment: There is no leak in that code. Nor are there any dangling pointers. The value of `nptr2` was complete nonsense to begin with, and later code execution didn't do it any favors. If you left out the delete ops you'd have two memory leaks. If you left out the reassignments to `NULL` you'd have two dangling pointers. You left out neither, so you have neither.

Comment: "dangling pointers that point to leaked memory" makes no sense. A dangling pointer is one that points to an already destroyed object. Leaked memory means you missed to destroy an object. The combination doesnt make sense

Comment: At least for new projects, instead of monitoring pointers, one could not use manual memory management anymore and use containers and smart pointers provided by C++.

Comment: This is quite low-level C++ programming. You rarely need this level; there are much better building blocks available that wrap `new/delete` for you. They're easier to use, and you'll get your work done faster.

Comment: @stefaanv Although the example code uses manual memory management unnecessarily, dangling pointers aren't a feature of manual memory management as such, and smart pointers and containers don't generally solve the problem of dangling pointers (except for shared pointers to some degree, but they have a cost).

Answer (score 2):

> dangling pointers that points to leakded memory?

A pointer that has leaked, by definition is not being pointed by anything. A dangling pointer by definition points to memory that hasn't been leaked. This is a contradiction.

> ```
> int *nptr2 = 2*nptr+ptr2;
> ```

This is ill-formed. Pointers cannot be multiplied by integers, and pointers cannot be added to pointers (I'm assuming the assumption is that result of the ill-formed multiplication is also a pointer). Furthermore, if this pointer arithmetic produced anything other than `nptr`,  `nptr+1`, `nptr2`, `nptr2+1`, then the result would technically be undefined.

> but dont know how to trace or monitor dangling pointers .

It's perfectly fine and normal to have dangling pointers. What isn't fine is indirecting through dangling pointers or relying on their value. At least for indirection, you can use an address sanitiser to try catch such bugs. It can find some uses of dangling pointers particularly those to dynamic memory such as the pointers in the question. It's not as good at detecting dangling pointers to automatic variables. On the other hand, compiler can catch simple cases such as returning pointer to local variable.

Alternatively, you can modify your program to use `std::shared_ptr` so that as long as you still hold a shared pointer, it cannot become dangling. This comes at a small cost of overhead, but it makes it much easier to reason about lifetime correctness.

Comment: thanks about your answer . i edit my question and i will be thankful if you take look at that .

Answer (score 1):

First of all "dangling pointers that points to leakded memory" makes no sense. I suppose you mistakenly use "leaked memory" for objects that are already destroyed. In your code there is no memory leak. You have a memory leak when you do **not** have a pointer to some dynamically allocated obejct anymore, as in:

```
{
    int* x = new int;
} // x goes out of scope, no way to delete the int
```

Further, it is not clear what this line is supposed to do `int *nptr2 = 2*nptr+ptr2;`. It is not valid C++, hence I am going to ignore it for the rest of the answer. Also the last two lines are not that relevant (maybe for code that comes after the shwon code but not here).

So we are left with:

```
 int * ptr = new int;
 int *nptr = ptr
 int * ptr2 = new int;
 delete ptr;
 delete ptr2;
```

You create two `int` via `new`. You `delete` two `int`. No memory is leaked. After `delete ptr` the pointer `nptr` points to a no longer existing object. `nptr` is said to be a dangling pointer.

With that out of the way, we can turn to your actual question: How to monitor dangling raw pointers?

You cannot. A raw pointer is rather primitive. It stores an address. And thats all. The pointer is not aware whether there is an object at that adress or not. This is one reason you should not use `new` and `delete` and raw pointers to manage memory. Use smart pointers. For example if you share ownership between two `std::shared_ptr` then the pointee will be kept alive as long as one of the shared pointers is alive. A shared pointer cannot dangle (unless you do something wrong).

Comment: thanks to your answer . i edit my question and i will be thankful if you take look at that

Comment: @esmaeil.zivari you should not edit the question after you got answers. With this new code in the question this and other answers are nonsense partly or as a whole. If you didnt ask the question you wanted to ask you should open a new question. I will reroll your edit

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you not use raw pointers. If you use smart pointers that then you will never(*) have a dangling pointer. The whole purpose of smart pointers is to ensure that the lifetime of both the pointer and what is pointed to is managed together.

Use std::unique_ptr, std::shared_ptr (and std::weak_ptr if needed).

You can use tools like Valgrind and AddressSanitizer to ensure that you do not use dangling pointers.

(*) never is perhaps too strong, at least make it more difficult.

Comment: please don't edit a question in a way that invalidates existing answers. OPs title doesnt make sense, but to clarify that should be part of answers. I rolled back your edit, because answers were invalidated by it